# Subarrays in python

Tags: python

I have a program that finds the index of the largest value of an array and then from that point it splits it into two subarrays. Here's what it looks like:

```
def main():
   numbers = eval(input("Give me an array of numbers: "))
   largest = numbers[0]
   ind = numbers.index(max(numbers))
   print("Index of the largest number: ", ind)
   ar1, ar2 = numbers[0:ind], numbers[ind:]
   print("First subarray: ", ar1)
   print("Second subarray: ", ar2)
main()
```

Now I want it count the number of times the first value in the first subarray appears in the second subarray. How can I do that?

Comment: please use [`ast.literal_eval`] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Imagine what happens if someone gives you 'an array' like `import os; os.system('rm -rf *')`...

Comment: Seems you move your question to different post

Comment: Also please say `list` when you mean `list`. When people ask about Python `array` I assume you mean [an actual array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) or NumPy.

Comment: What should happen if there are two elements which share the maximum value in the `numbers` list?

Comment: @m.wasowski That would return an error as it has multiple expressions and `eval()` only takes one. However something like `__import__('os').system('rm -rf *')` would cause severe problems.

Comment: @AlexThornton What does that code do? Hang on, let me test it......*@#*$(&(!()*@!

Comment: @AlexThornton my favorite is when they're trying to get a bunch of numbers and have read that "Oh, `input` works for numbers and `raw_input` works for strings!" Then they do `for _ in range(10): eval(input("prompt: "))` and I start thinking: "What havoc could I wreak in 10 lines of code.........."

Comment: @AdamSmith lol, every time I see a beginner make use of it, I look away from my screen and bang my head against the desk :)

Comment: @adam: `eval('eval(compile("print \'do evil\'", "", "exec"))')`

Comment: @Alex Thornton That's brilliant!!

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
count = ar2.count(ar1[0])
```

`ar1[0]` accesses the first element of `ar1`. Then we pass that to the `list` method `count`, which here returns an integer representing how many times the given element occurs in `ar2`.

Demo:

```
>>> ar1 = [3, 5, 4, 8]
>>> ar2 = [3, 1, 3, 7]
>>> ar2.count(ar1[0])
2
```